# Create columns from pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to calculate the rating difference by gender for each movie. (IMDB dataset)
This is the groupby method i've used:

```py
df.groupby(['movie title', 'gender'])['rating'].mean()
```

And the head:

[image]

I'd like to create a new dataframe with 2 columns of rating for each movie - for male and female.
For example, the first row will be like:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `unstack`:

```
(df.groupby(['movie title', 'gender'])
   ['rating'].mean()
   .unstack()
   .reset_index()      # turn `movie_title` into a normal column.
)
```

And you should get `F,M` as column names. Rename as you wish.